# how to upload image by using dropzone.js

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I would like to use `dropzone` plugin to upload image or images.
but it doesn't upload images :

```
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone dz-clickable" action="http://www.****/Upload.php">
                        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Submit</button>
                        <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div></form>
                    <div>
```

my script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {

        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 100,
        maxFiles: 100,
        url:'http://****/Upload.php',
        // Dropzone settings
        init: function() {
            var myDropzone = this;

            this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });
            this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
                console.log('sending');
            });
            this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
                console.log('success:'+response);
                this.options.url = 'http://www.***/Upload.php';
            });
            this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
                console.log('error:'+response);
            });
        }

    }

});
```

on my console I got this response:

[image]

Comment: So what's the return code from the server? Try using `console.log('success:', response);` instead. If `response` is an object you wouldn't see its content if you try to concat it to `'success:'` string.

Comment: I changed it to `console.log('success:', response);` but I got the same output.